# Firebase .childAdded and activity Indicator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I faced with a problem when I start activity indicator before API call and stop after, however I'm unable to do it properly if I populate TableView with .childAdded. Since .childAdded calls only when child is added, my activity indicator is always loading. For example:

```
func parseData() {
    
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    
    DataService.instance.SOME_DATA.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    
        if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            let data = someData(data: snapshot)
            self.array.append(data)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    })
}
```

So basically if there is no any value .childAdded will not be called and activity indicator will never stop since it stops only when tableView is reloaded.
Could some please advise how to do it properly? Much appreciated.

**Some updates based on the advised answer**:

I'll give an example based on the chat app, it would be much easier to understand.
I have the following database structure:

```
user_messages
   unique_user_id
      unique_user_chat_id
          unique_message_1
          unique_message_2
          unique_message_3
          unique_message_4
messages
   unique_message_1
          text...
   unique_message_2
          text...
   unique_message_3
          text...
   unique_message_4
          text...
```

I have 2 View Controllers and each has a TableView

[image]

Parent view controller fetch all unique_user_chat_id and when client press on the chosen chat, second View Controller populate all Childs from 'messages' object. So basically second View Controller doesn't need to call function .observeSingleEvent(of: .value to fetch unique_user_chat_id, only Childs .childAdded in 'messages' object.

Answer (score 0):

As you observe `childAdded`, as you said this might never get called.

change `childAdded` to `valueChanged` and observe `childAdded`. Add the animation call to `valueChanged`.

You shouldn't set an activity indicator when observing childAdded, only when fetching initial data.

```
func fetchData() {

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    DataService.instance.SOME_DATA.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // Handle current value and stop activity indicator 
         if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
              let data = someData(data: snapshot)
              self.array.append(data)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
           self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

           // Observe new childs added
           self.observeData()
       }
    })
 }

func observeData() {

    DataService.instance.SOME_DATA.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            let data = someData(data: snapshot)
            self.array.append(data)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this and from the first look it will work however if a user will have an internet connection problem? Animation will start, API will not be called and animation will stop in 2 second (delay as example).

Comment: @Sargot I amended my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Could you please check my updated question based on your answer and advise if I did it correctly? Also I'm not sure which animation should I call?

Comment: But if I do not need to fetch the parent? I mean I populate the tableView only with childs, like a chat as example. My parent is in tableView from which I segue to details view and there I populate my childs.

Comment: @Sargot I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? Don't use an activity indicator when you are observing `childAdded`, this is not guaranteed to call. If you want to fetch a list of messages, use `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,` this is guaranteed to be fetched once, and after you can observe new messages.  Use the activity indicator when observing a single value. 

As to your comment regarding the parent, this will only fetch the child's of the parent, not the list of parents, but that depends how you have set up your database architecture.

Comment: I understand all what you are saying and I do apologize if my question was not clear for you. I updated my question with an example again, so now you can see what I want to achieve. if you have a time, please advise. Much appreciated.